# Apt-get error "undefined symbol: xml_sethashsalt" when install/update python3

Tags: python-3.x

It just keeps failing when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade` because it failed to upgrade some package that based on Python3. The error was: `undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt`. I'd been searching around for solutions but there is no such answer on StackOverflow.

Then at the end, I found an answer on not very related question mention that the library path for `libexpat.so.1` pointing to `/usr/local/lib/` may cause the issue. So I try to rename `libexpat.so.1` to `libexpat.so.1-bk` then it works.

So I just re-post it here, hope it helps for anyone facing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have broken your system.

If you are using `apt`, the `/usr/local/` should never be used.

If you are using `/usr/local/`, do not use `apt` to manage your installation.